# SMS Application

Tags: java, php, .net, sms, gateway

I just wanted to know is there any free sms gateway for sending SMS. If there is one, how to go on to developing my free sms service/software?

Any guidelines please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - Kannel is a free open source SMS/WAP gateway. But you still need to connect to the service providers. Its prably a lot simpler to go via an aggregator - they'll supply APIs.

Alternatively just plug a GSM modem into your server (most modern phones will provide this service)

> my free sms service

Most service providers charge you for sending texts

C.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a good free SMS provider but i can certainly set you on your way on developing SMS applications.

First of all check out this very good tutorial: http://www.developershome.com/sms/smsIntro.asp.

I think all you need for a starters is your own SMS modem and a prepaid card to start testing out the SMS protocol.

As for the SMS gateway i would suggest trying out Clickatell. We were very pleased with it when we first used it, back in early 2009.

Good luck!

Comment: funny that right here next to your post appears a Clickatell ad :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find a free webbased sms gateway. I would use a downloadable software and connect an ordinary cell phone. That way you can achieve similar results without the expensive per sms costs.

Also, if you are able to use a text messaging software that can connect to an Android based phone you can achieve some amazing speeds, and offer your sms services very longcode. (Which is a regular phone number).

Good luck, the reason I know this is because we have achieved this in our text messaging software http://www.firetext.com