# how to send SMS to mobiles using JAVA

Tags: java, sms

I want to send SMS to mobiles.Can any one help me how to send SMS to mobiles using JAVA. Is there any Free API?

Any ideas?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545441/how-can-i-send-an-sms-from-java][1]

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115990/sms-application][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545441/how-can-i-send-an-sms-from-java
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115990/sms-application

Comment: I've been thinking about writing a bot to provide comments like these. Are you a bot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have done this before by installing and using [kannel](http://www.kannel.org/). It can then be used with a java-client or a library like [kannel java api](http://kanneljavaapi.sourceforge.net/).

This is not going to be a simple task, though. There probably are easier alternatives.

Comment: anytime. good luck if you try doing kannel. it can be daunting at times, but when you understand whats going down, and get it running, it's very rewarding.

Answer (score 1):

You need access to sms gateway.Providers use different protocols SOAP, rest.
There is no free working sms gateways  as far is know.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague.. 
You can send SMS using SMS Gateway where they would provide you with the REST API calls to send SMS's to the numbers..