# How to send SMS in Java

Tags: java, sms

What are the possible ways to send and receive sms from Java application?

How?

Answer (score 26):

*(Disclaimer: I work at Twilio)*

[Twilio offers a Java SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install) for sending SMS via the Twilio REST API.

Comment: what if i want to recieve it on my server?

Comment: You would sign up for a Twilio account, then assign a URL to be hit when an incoming message is received: http://www.twilio.com/sms/

Answer (score 19):

if all you want is simple notifications, many carriers support SMS via email; see [SMS through E-Mail](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/939/sms_email_cingular_nextel_sprint_tmobile_verizon_virgin/)

Comment: This is simple, but only if you know the carrier and can verify that their email-to-SMS feature works as expected for a particular number. (There may be some carrier differences!) This can be handy, but is not a general purpose solution.

Answer (score 12):

There is an API called SMSLib, it's really awesome.
http://smslib.org/

Now you have a lot of Saas providers that can give you this service using their APIs

Ex: mailchimp, esendex, Twilio, ...

Answer (score 10):

The best SMS API I've seen in Java is JSMPP. It is powerful, easy to use, and I used it myself for an enterprise-level application (sending over 20K SMS messages daily).

> This API created to reduce the verbosity of the existing SMPP API.
>   It's very simple and easy to use because it hides the complexity of
>   the low level protocol communication such as automatically enquire
>   link request-response.

- https://code.google.com/p/jsmpp/

I've tried some other APIs such as Ozeki, but most of them either is commercial or has limitation in its throughput (i.e can't send more than 3 SMS messages in a second, for example).

Comment: Looks like it has moved to : https://jsmpp.org/ , 
examples at https://github.com/uudashr/jsmpp

Answer (score 9):

### You Can Do this With A GSM Modem and Java Communications Api [Tried And Tested]

1. First You Need TO Set Java Comm Api

   [This Article Describes In Detail How to Set Up Communication Api](http://kishor15389.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-install-java-communications.html)
2. Next You Need A GSM Modem (preferably sim900 Module )
3. Java JDK latest version preferable
4. AT Command Guide

   ### Code

   package sample;

   ```
       import java.io.*;
       import java.util.*;

       import gnu.io.*;

       import java.io.*;


       import org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.Main;

       import sun.audio.*;

       public class GSMConnect implements SerialPortEventListener, 
        CommPortOwnershipListener {

        private static String comPort = "COM6"; // This COM Port must be connect with GSM Modem or your mobile phone
        private String messageString = "";
        private CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        private Enumeration portList;
        private InputStream inputStream = null;
        private OutputStream outputStream = null;
        private SerialPort serialPort;
        String readBufferTrial = "";
        /** Creates a new instance of GSMConnect */
        public GSMConnect(String comm) {

          this.comPort = comm;

        }

        public boolean init() {
          portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
          while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
            if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
              if (portId.getName().equals(comPort)) {
                  System.out.println("Got PortName");
                return true;
              }
            }
          }
          return false;
        }

        public void checkStatus() {
          send("AT+CREG?\r\n");
        }



        public void send(String cmd) {
          try {
            outputStream.write(cmd.getBytes());
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

        public void sendMessage(String phoneNumber, String message) {
              char quotes ='"';
          send("AT+CMGS="+quotes + phoneNumber +quotes+ "\r\n");
          try {
           Thread.sleep(2000);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
           //   send("AT+CMGS=\""+ phoneNumber +"\"\r\n");
          send(message + '\032');
          System.out.println("Message Sent");
        }

        public void hangup() {
          send("ATH\r\n");
        }

        public void connect() throws NullPointerException {
          if (portId != null) {
            try {
              portId.addPortOwnershipListener(this);

              serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("MobileGateWay", 2000);
              serialPort.setSerialPortParams(115200,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            } catch (PortInUseException | UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
              inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
              outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
              /** These are the events we want to know about*/
              serialPort.addEventListener(this);
              serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
              serialPort.notifyOnRingIndicator(true);
            } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

       //Register to home network of sim card

            send("ATZ\r\n");

          } else {
            throw new NullPointerException("COM Port not found!!");
          }
        }

        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) {
          switch (serialPortEvent.getEventType()) {
            case SerialPortEvent.BI:
            case SerialPortEvent.OE:
            case SerialPortEvent.FE:
            case SerialPortEvent.PE:
            case SerialPortEvent.CD:
            case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
            case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
            case SerialPortEvent.RI:     
            case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:

              byte[] readBuffer = new byte[2048];
              try {
                while (inputStream.available() > 0) 
                {
                  int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);

                  System.out.print(numBytes);
                  if((readBuffer.toString()).contains("RING")){
                  System.out.println("Enter Inside if RING Loop");    



                  }
                }

                System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
              } catch (IOException e) {
              }
              break;
          }
        }
        public void outCommand(){
            System.out.print(readBufferTrial);
        }
        public void ownershipChange(int type) {
          switch (type) {
            case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_UNOWNED:
              System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_UNOWNED");
              break;
            case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_OWNED:
              System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_OWNED");
              break;
            case CommPortOwnershipListener.PORT_OWNERSHIP_REQUESTED:
              System.out.println(portId.getName() + ": PORT_INUSED");
              break;
          }

        }
        public void closePort(){

           serialPort.close(); 
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
          GSMConnect gsm = new GSMConnect(comPort);
          if (gsm.init()) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Initialization Success");
              gsm.connect();
              Thread.sleep(5000);
              gsm.checkStatus();
              Thread.sleep(5000);

              gsm.sendMessage("+91XXXXXXXX", "Trial Success");

              Thread.sleep(1000);

              gsm.hangup();
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              gsm.closePort();
              gsm.outCommand();
              System.exit(1);


            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          } else {
            System.out.println("Can't init this card");
          }
        }


           }
   ```

Answer (score 8):

You can use Nexmo to [send SMS](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2017/05/03/send-sms-messages-with-java-dr/) as well as [receive SMS](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2017/05/31/receive-sms-messages-java-dr/).

Sending SMS with the [Nexmo Java Library](https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-java) is fairly straightforward. After [creating a new account](https://dashboard.nexmo.com/sign-up), renting a virtual number, and getting your API key & secret you can use the library to send SMS like so:

```
  public class SendSMS {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          AuthMethod auth = new TokenAuthMethod(API_KEY, API_SECRET);
          NexmoClient client = new NexmoClient(auth);

          TextMessage message = new TextMessage(FROM_NUMBER, TO_NUMBER, "Hello from Nexmo!");

          //There may be more than one response if the SMS sent is more than 160 characters.
          SmsSubmissionResult[] responses = client.getSmsClient().submitMessage(message);
            for (SmsSubmissionResult response : responses) {
            System.out.println(response);
          }
      }
  }
```

To receive SMS you'll need to set up a server that consumes a webhook. That's fairly simple as well. I recommend checking out our tutorial on [receiving SMS with Java](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2017/05/31/receive-sms-messages-java-dr/).

*Disclosure: I work for Nexmo*

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways :
First : Use a SMS  API Gateway which you need to pay for it , maybe you find some trial       even free ones but it's scarce .
Second : To use AT command with a modem GSM connected to your laptop .
that's all

Answer (score 2):

OMK.smpp. API. it's base on SMPP
and simulator is also available for free

LOGICA SMPP API.

And another option is [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) a free WAP and SMS gateway.

Comment: Configuring kannel makes you drop a sweat if you manage to configure it with modem , kindly share the procedureS.

Answer (score 2):

TextMarks gives you access to its shared shortcode to send and receive text messages from your app via their API.  Messages come from/to 41411 (instead of e.g. a random phone# and unlike e-mail gateways you have the full 160 chars to work with).

You can also tell people to text in your keyword(s) to 41411 to invoke various functionality in your app.  There is a JAVA API client along with several other popular languages and very comprehensive documentation and technical support.

The 14 day free trial can be easily extended for developers who are still testing it out and building their apps.

Check it out here:  [TextMarks API Info](https://www.textmarks.com/front/dev/)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a cloud based solution like Twilio. Cloud based solutions are cost-effective, than an in-house solution as the there is no ongoing maintenance, required. SMS through email is not an elegant solution, as you have to get the carrier information from the user and you can never be sure that you can text all mobile numbers.
I am using twilio java api in my web application, to send sms from serverside. within few minutes, you can integrate with your app.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install

Here's an example sending an SMS message from the docs:

```
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.MessageFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Message;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

  // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "{{ account_sid }}";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "{{ auth_token }}";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    // Build a filter for the MessageList
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "Test Twilio message"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "+14159352345"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+14158141829"));

    MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory();
    Message message = messageFactory.create(params);
    System.out.println(message.getSid());
  }
}
```

Comment: Paid but it is less than a cent per text message.

Answer (score 1):

You can you LOGICA SMPP Java API for sending and Recieving SMS in Java application.
LOGICA SMPP is well proven api in telecom application. Logica API also provide you with signalling capicity on TCP/IP connection.

You can directly integrate with various telecom operator accross the world.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're going to work and who your provider is.

If you work with a sms-gateway company you'll probably work through SMPP protocol (3.4 is still the most common), then have a look on OpenSMPP and jSMPP. These are powerful libs to work with SMPP.

If you're going to work with your own hardware (f.e. a gsm-modem) the easiest way to send messages is through AT commands, they differ depends on the model, so, you should find out what AT commands is supported by your modem. Next, if your modem has an IP and open to connection, you can send commands through java socket

```
Socket smppSocket = new Socket("YOUR_MODEM_IP", YOUR_MODEM_PORT);
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(smppSocket.getOutputStream());
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(smppSocket.getInputStream());

os.write(some_byte_array[]);
is.readLine();
```

Otherwise you'll work through a COM port, but the method is the same (sending AT commands), you can find more information how to work with serial ports [here](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Twilio](http://twilio.com) for this. But if you are looking for some tricky workaround you can follow the workaround I have mentioned below.

This is not possible for receiving sms. But this is a tricky method you can use to send sms to number of clients. You can use twitter API. We can follow twitter account from our mobile phone with a sms. We just have to send sms to twitter. Imagine we create a twitter account with the user name of `@username`. Then we can send sms to 40404 as shown below.

`follow @username`

Then we start to get tweets which are tweeted in that account.

So after we create a twitter account then we can use Twitter API to post tweets from that account. Then all the clients who have follow that account as I mentioned before start to receiving tweets.

You can learn how to post tweets with twitter API from following link.

[Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries)

Before you start developing you have to get permission to use twitter api. You can get access to twitter api from following link.

[Twitter Developer Console](https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps)

This is not the best solution for your problem.But hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

We also love Java in [Wavecell](http://wavecell.com), but this question can be answered without language-specific details since we have a [REST API](https://developer.wavecell.com) which will cover most of your needs:

```
curl -X "POST" https://api.wavecell.com/sms/v1/amazing_hq/single \
    -u amazing:1234512345 \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d $'{ "source": "AmazingDev", "destination": "+6512345678", "text": "Hello, World!" }'
```

Look at this questions if you have problems with sending HTTP requests in Java:

- [HTTP POST using JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java)
- [How can I send json object in http post in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782266/how-can-i-send-json-object-in-http-post-in-java)

For specific cases you can also consider using the [SMPP API](https://developer.wavecell.com/v1/smpp-guide) and already mentioned [JSMPP](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsmpp/) library will help with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Ogham](https://groupe-sii.github.io/ogham/) library. The code to send SMS is easy to write (it automatically handles character encoding and message splitting). The real SMS is sent either using SMPP protocol (standard SMS protocol) or through a provider.
You can even test your code locally with a SMPP server to check the result of your SMS before paying for real SMS sending.

```
package fr.sii.ogham.sample.standard.sms;

import java.util.Properties;

import fr.sii.ogham.core.builder.MessagingBuilder;
import fr.sii.ogham.core.exception.MessagingException;
import fr.sii.ogham.core.service.MessagingService;
import fr.sii.ogham.sms.message.Sms;

public class BasicSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        // [PREPARATION] Just do it once at startup of your application
        
        // configure properties (could be stored in a properties file or defined
        // in System properties)
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("ogham.sms.smpp.host", "<your server host>");                                 // <1>
        properties.setProperty("ogham.sms.smpp.port", "<your server port>");                                 // <2>
        properties.setProperty("ogham.sms.smpp.system-id", "<your server system ID>");                       // <3>
        properties.setProperty("ogham.sms.smpp.password", "<your server password>");                         // <4>
        properties.setProperty("ogham.sms.from.default-value", "<phone number to display for the sender>");  // <5>
        // Instantiate the messaging service using default behavior and
        // provided properties
        MessagingService service = MessagingBuilder.standard()                                               // <6>
                .environment()
                    .properties(properties)                                                                  // <7>
                    .and()
                .build();                                                                                    // <8>
        // [/PREPARATION]
        
        // [SEND A SMS]
        // send the sms using fluent API
        service.send(new Sms()                                                                               // <9>
                        .message().string("sms content")
                        .to("+33752962193"));
        // [/SEND A SMS]
    }
}
```

There are many other [features](https://groupe-sii.github.io/ogham/v3.0.0/user-manual.html#sms-usage) and [samples](https://github.com/groupe-sii/ogham/tree/v3.0.0/sample-standard-usage/src/main/java/fr/sii/ogham/sample/standard/sms) / [spring samples](https://github.com/groupe-sii/ogham/tree/v3.0.0/sample-spring-usage/src/main/java/fr/sii/ogham/sample/springboot).

Answer (score -2):

You can use AT & T commands for sending sms using GSM modem.