# How can i call my page using sms?

Tags: java, jsp, sms

I want to develop a web application in JSP ,in which a user can sent their id using their mobile number and after that they will get their data like total amount,balance etc.
I am not getting how can i do this?
If you can provide any api name and example that will be great for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You accept user phone no with some form persist it.

  - You map phone no with user account
  - Write a service which will send SMS to mobile no, after reading user data on timely basis.

[Here you can check how to send sms from JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570410/how-to-send-sms)

Answer (score 0):

To interact with a GSM Modem (such as a mobile phone), you can use [SMSLib](http://smslib.org/). You will have to write some sort of backend though since SMSLib is a Java library.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR using the WAP protocol automatically sends the MSISDN (phone number) included into the WAP request. This may be a starting point (get the client to execute a WAP request to your server).