# sending sms to cell phone using some java program 

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to send sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570410/how-to-send-sms)

I need to send some sms to my customers regarding my site ..how can i achieve this ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570410/how-to-send-sms

Answer (score 0):

If you mean in any quantity at all, you'll probably need to use an sms gateway service.