# How to post the following Json array in Android

Tags: android

```
[{
 "Name":"abc"
 "Place":"def"

}]
```

The above is the Json array. How to post a Json array to webserver in Android? Is there any sample code available?

Comment: Did you try anything? for example http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html

Comment: What do you mean ? Send this array as string (the string that you put as code in your question) in a POST http var to a web server ?

Comment: Hi gahfy ! Can I convert this array as String ,add as parameter and set it to "setEntity()" method and post

Comment: yes, you can >> http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: But how is your json array in your java code ? May you add samples of your JSON code ?

Comment: Hi gahfy ! my jsonArray code is as below:JSONArray finalArray= new JSONArray();
JSONObject Details = new JSONObject();
Details.put("Name" , "abc");
Details.put("Place" , "bdc");
finalArray.put(Details );  Gahfy ! please help me in sorting out this issue?

Comment: Here is another link to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like that:

1) Build the JSON object

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put("Name", name);
params.put("Place", place);
```

2) Post to server

```
private HttpURLConnection connection;
connection = (HttpURLConnection) <your_url>.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

byte[] outputBytes = <your_json_object>.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
os.write(outputBytes);
os.close();
....
```

Comment: This is JSON object. I want to post JSON array  to server

Comment: My json array will be like below : JSONArray finalArray= new JSONArray();
JSONObject Details = new JSONObject();
Details.put("Name" , "abc");
Details.put("Place" , "bdc");
finalArray.put(Details );

Comment: you don't post a JSONArray. You post a JSONObject that is put() with a name as the key, and the JSONArray as the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using HttpPost request and string entity to send JSON use following code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

HttpUriRequest request;

request = new HttpPost(url);

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(**<-Your JSON->**);
    ((HttpPost) request).setEntity(entity);


((HttpPost) request).setHeader("Content-Type",
"application/json");

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Comment: Hi mittal ! I got 500 error when I try to post data to server. Is it related to client code or its server problem

Comment: 500 is internal server error try using postman or some rest client to check your services