# httpClient.getConnectionManager() is deprecated - what should be used instead?

Tags: java, apache, http

I have inherited the code

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
...
HttpClient httpclient = createHttpClientOrProxy();

    try {
        HttpPost postRequest = postRequest(data, url);
        body = readResponseIntoBody(body, httpclient, postRequest);
    } catch( IOException ioe ) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot post/read", ioe);
    } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();  // ** Deprecated
    }


private HttpClient createHttpClientOrProxy() {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    /*
     * Set an HTTP proxy if it is specified in system properties.
     * 
     * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html
     * http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java
     */
    if( isSet(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost")) ) {
        log.warn("http.proxyHost = " + System.getProperty("http.proxyHost") );
        log.warn("http.proxyPort = " + System.getProperty("http.proxyPort"));
        int port = 80;
        if( isSet(System.getProperty("http.proxyPort")) ) {
            port = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("http.proxyPort"));
        }
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(System.getProperty("http.proxyHost"), port, "http");
// @Deprecated methods here... getParams() and ConnRoutePNames
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
    }
    return httpclient;
}
```

`getConnectionManager()` reads "

```
@Deprecated
ClientConnectionManager getConnectionManager()

Deprecated. (4.3) use HttpClientBuilder.
Obtains the connection manager used by this client.
```

The docs for HttpClientBuilder seem sparse and simply say:

```
Builder for CloseableHttpClient instances.
```

However if I replace `HttpClient` with `CloseableHttpClient` the method still seems `@Deprecated`.

How can I use a non-Deprecated method?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get the `ClientConnectionManager`? Why?

Comment: Could you post more code? Like how the `httpClient` is initialized.

Comment: I have posted the code for creating the HttpClient. I can't answer "Why" as I didn't write the original code.

Comment: Can you Please explain little more about this ?                    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();. I am created the Object for HttpClientBuilder httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create(); how can we modify related to the httpclient 4.3.3 jar

Comment: It is not deprecated: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#getConnectionManager()

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Instead of creating a new instance of `HttpClient`, use the Builder. You would get a `CloseableHttpClient`.

e.g usage:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setProxy(proxy).build()
```

Instead of using `getConnectionManager().shutdown()`, use the `close()` method instead on `CloseableHttpClient`.