# How to Make an HTTP POST with JSON object as data?

Tags: java, json, post

Can anyone refer me to a single, simple resource explaining how to in Java make an HTTP POST with JSON object as data?  I want to be able to do this without using Apache HTTP Client.

The following is what I've done so far.  I am trying to figure out how to modify it with JSON.

```
 public class HTTPPostRequestWithSocket {

     public void sendRequest(){

         try {
            String params = URLEncoder.encode("param1", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
            params += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("param2", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");

            String hostname = "nameofthewebsite.com";
            int port = 80;

           InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
           Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);
           String path = "/nameofapp";

        // Send headers
        BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF8"));
        wr.write("POST "+path+" HTTP/1.0rn");
        wr.write("Content-Length: "+params.length()+"rn");
        wr.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencodedrn");
        wr.write("rn");

        // Send parameters
        wr.write(params);
        wr.flush();

        // Get response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String line;

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            }

        wr.close();
        rd.close();
        socket.close();//Should this be closed at this point?
        }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

}

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: I just added what I've done so far.

Comment: This seems to be the solution 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181775/2010052

Comment: You just need to use JSONObject mycontent=new JSONObject(); put you content in mycontent object and post it

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, Tejas.  It will take me a little time to look at it and figure it out and make sure that it is what I need.

Comment: I appreciate the information, Prashant.  That's definitely something to move forward with.

Comment: Tejas, thanks for the information.  But that example appears to us e Apache HTTP Client, which I am trying to avoid using.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a string.

Just add the json objet as a post value.

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jsonData", new JSONObject(json)));//json
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "somevalue"));//regular post value
```