# Can't translate Postman request to Java

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x, androidhttpclient, postman

I have a post request working successfully in Postman, but when I make the same request from my Android app, I get "Internal Server Error". Do you see any difference between these two requests?

Postman

[image: Postman request]

Android App

```
class MakeRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://sample.com/test");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httppost.setHeader("Authorization", getB64Auth("username", "password"));

            try {
                JSONObject identity = new JSONObject();
                identity.put("type", "number");
                identity.put("endpoint", "12345");

                JSONObject options = new JSONObject();
                options.put("num", "12345");

                JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
                body.put("identity", identity);
                body.put("method", "test");
                body.put("options", options);

                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(body.toString());
                httppost.setEntity(se);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("IOException", e.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("JSONException", e.toString());
            }

            try {
                ResponseHandler handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Log.d("HttpResponse", handler.handleResponse(response).toString());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.d("ClientProtocolException", e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("IOException", e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }

        private String getB64Auth (String key, String secret) {
            String source=key+":"+secret;
            String ret="Basic "+Base64.encodeToString(source.getBytes(),Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP);
            return ret;
        }

    }
```

Other thoughts/hints:

Authentication is working properly in the java code. I tried with wrong username & password, and I got "Invalid Authorization"

The JSON string is *exactly* the same as the one in postman. I printed body.toString(), copied and pasted into Postman, and the request worked fine in Postman.

Comment: take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java/7181775#7181775

Comment: Thanks for the link! I used that answer, but changed content-type to application/json to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

you should change `httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");` to `httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/form-data");` or `httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

this should solve your issue.