# Broken Array in PHP

Tags: java, php

I wrote a Java program that accepts a JSON object and send to php. However when I receive the JSON in PHP a broken or incomplete array is returned as shown below.

I am sending this JSON object from java and in java I am able to print the JSON object and it shows well:

```json
{"Description":"now locatio-n","ReportedByFirstname":null,"DateReported":null,"Name":"now","FacilityId":"13692","LocationDescription":"now locatio-n","ReportedByPersonId":null,"ReportedByMobileNumber":null,"StatusId":"22","ReportedByLastname":null,"ReportedByEmail":null,"Id":"957394","PriorityId":"2","LocationLat":"","LocationLong":""}
```

In PHP I print the value as shown below:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

and the results are as follows: PLEASE NOTE THE FIRST ELEMENT DESCRIPTION IS NOT FULLY SHOWN.

```
Array
(
    [defect] => -n","ReportedByFirstname":null,"DateReported":null,"Name":"now","FacilityId":"13692","LocationDescription":"now locatio-n","ReportedByPersonId":null,"ReportedByMobileNumber":null,"StatusId":"22","ReportedByLastname":null,"ReportedByEmail":null,"Id":"957394","PriorityId":"2","LocationLat":"","LocationLong":""}
)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java

Comment: json is object not array you may need [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Your using is valid. I think you  are printing values wrongly!!are you directly printing the json value using php?instead of `print_r($_POST);` try `json_decode($_POST);`

Comment: Thank you for the respond but it gives me this error:      json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given when code when using        print_r(json_decode($_POST));