# Not able to pass parameters in HTTP POST using Java - getting 400 response status

Tags: java, rest, http-post, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

My question might seem like possible duplicate of posts mentioned in stackoverflow, but none of those are able to resolve my issue. I am trying to pass some parameters with my URL using HTTP POST method. Following is my code :

```
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://urlname/_search");

    List<NameValuePair> nameValue = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValue.add(new BasicNameValuePair("size", "1"));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValue));


    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

I get 400 response status when running the code. I want to basically run http://urlname/_search?size=1 which runs well on browser directly as URI. I think I am doing some basic syntax error. Also, using the POST request (http://urlname/_search) without parameters is working well and yielding the expected results. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: `_search?size=1` looks like a GET request, not a POST

Comment: Following is the request i want to execute. How do I form it in java program? POST http://url/_search
{
    "size":10
}

Comment: I think what you have is fine, but as I said, since that url you mentioned works in the browser, it would seem it is a GET, and not a POST. You can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests) to do some more extensive testing, if you wish

Comment: Though, you seem to be wanting to POST JSON, and not a UrlEncodedFormEntity

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19912858/2308683)

Comment: I tested the http://url/_search with key value as (size,1) in postman as POST request. I works perfectly well. I am not sure why it is not working in Java program.

Comment: Does it work without the size parameter?

Comment: Your Java code doesn't set the Content-Type header.

Comment: It works with JSONObject. Thank you @cricket_007 :)