# How to send nested JSON input to Restful web service (using Java)?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, jax-rs

How to send nested JSON input to Restful web service (using Java)?

eg. JSON input

```
{
  "item1": [
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "value": "value1",
      "subitems": [
        {
          "sname": "sname1",
          "svalue": "svalue1"
        },
        {
          "sname": "sname2",
          "svalue": "svalue2"
        }
      ],
      "attributes": [
        {
          "length": 25,
          "height": 25,
          "width": 30
        },
        {
          "length": 35,
          "height": 35,
          "width": 40
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: check this json with http://jsonlint.com - it is not valid

Comment: Thanks Scary! Please ignore the parsing error. It's just an example to show the hierarchy. i.e. nesting

Comment: there's already a stack post for this have a look.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class to map you json like this :

```
     public class item {
        private String name;
        private String value;
        private List<SubItem> subitems;
        private List<Attribute> attributes;
        // add here getters, setters and constructor
     }

     public class SubItem{
        private String name;
        private String svalue;
        //add here getters, setters and constructor
     }
     public class Attribute{
        private Integer length;
        private Integer height;
        private Integer width;
        //add here getters, setters and constructor
     }
```

Comment: Thanks! But how will we accept the Class in WebService Post method.

Comment: like this : 
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

 public ReturnedView yourMethod(Item item)  {
....}

Comment: Thanks maad el yadari. So we can't use annotation like @Queryparam for such objects?

Comment: Getting following error:
error occured in reading JSON :
java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2433)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2366)
 at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1162)

Comment: Back end code was not expecting any Custom Object. Instead of passing Item object, I passed bodyObject and  then mapping it with Item further using ObjectMapper.