# Can someone help me with passing JSON data in body for HTTP post call

Tags: java, json

Can someone help me with passing below `JSON data` in body for my `HTTP POST` call..

```
{
    "name": "ABC",
    "user": "fl9f03fe24a2c4a4b51a4d75",
    "data": 
    {
        "details": "component",
        "Key": "123",
        "region": "server-23"
    }

}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? share your code.

Comment: where are you making this POST call ? are you getting any error ?

Comment: A probable answer is already in the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java)

Comment: @MusakkhirSayyed : 



I am creating below JSON data to pass in my HTTP call but unable to add values to object "data" below is the code.




`JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("name", "ABC");
obj.put("user","fl9f03fe24a2c4a4b51a4d75");
datanew = (JSONObject) obj.get("data");
datanew.put("details", "component");
datanew.put("Key", "123");
datanew.put("region","server-23")`

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is your code (I edited your post, please accept it):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("name", "ABC");
obj.put("user","fl9f03fe24a2c4a4b51a4d75");
datanew = (JSONObject) obj.get("data");
datanew.put("details", "component");
datanew.put("Key", "123");
datanew.put("region","server-23");
```

Your JSON object `obj` is new and empty, it doesn't contain anything. So you can't `get("data")` before you `put("data")` first. Try this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("name", "ABC");
obj.put("user","fl9f03fe24a2c4a4b51a4d75");

JSONObject datanew = new JSONObject();
datanew.put("details", "component");
datanew.put("Key", "123");
datanew.put("region","server-23");

obj.put("data", datanew);
```