# Quotation marks in json to url

Tags: java, android, json, url

I have following problem. I have android app with some data and I want to post json data to web api. Api notice when you load url with json like this.

```
http://example.eu/xx/yyyy/{"data1":"TEXT","data2":"TEXT","data3:"TEXT","data4":"TEXT"}
```

but  when I do it like this ....

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.eu/xx/yyyy/"+json);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
```

It work but in api i see this

> "{\"id\":\"14D20E65-5701-4519-AD87-1FBBD80706CF\",\"stav\":
>   \"SENT\"}"

There are quotation marks with backslash. And I don't know how to remove them. (I think the problem is when i load string url to URL class)

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java

Comment: why don't you POST data?