# Http Parameters as Json

Tags: java, html, apache, http, web

One of the requests on my page has some parameters and in Firefox DevTool it looks like:
[image]

How is it possible to create this structure in url or just add parameters in Java?

Usually I use `Apache HttpPost` and then:

```
 ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
  postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "value"));
  httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters, "UTF-8"));
```

but have no idea how to pass json as my request parameter...

@Update

So in my example should it looks like:

```
Map<String, Object> comMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> iMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> mainMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

comMap.put("p","A");

iMap.put("com", comMap);
iMap.put("t", "b");

mainMap.put("ex", null);
mainMap.put("i(2)", null);
mainMap.put("i(3)", iMap);
```

where `i(2)` is `i` from second line and `i(3)` is `i` from third line?
How is it possible to add map to `HttpPost` (if it is correct)?

@Update

I send requests by using:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost;
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpPost = new HttpPost("myUrl");
httpPost.setHeader("headerKey","headerValue");

ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("paramKey", "false"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters, "UTF-8"));
HttpResponse response = httpClient .execute(httpPost);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic `Map` acts as a `key => value`, something like this:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> comList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
ArrayList<NameValuePair> iList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
ArrayList<NameValuePair> mainList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

comList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p", "A");

iList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("com", comList);
iList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("t", "b"));

mainList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ex", null));
mainList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("i(2)", null));
mainList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("i(3)", iList));
```

Comment: I hide data on screen by black area and only first characters are visible so I put these characters in my edit.

Comment: Oh yes, the edit you made will give the result shown in the image

Comment: and how could I pass this map as `HttpPost` parameter?

Comment: Show us the piece of code where you make the request

Comment: It means that I can not put Map instead of ArrayList as `setEntity` method

Comment: `httpost.setEntity(mainMap);`
`httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");`

Comment: Dont forget to set `Content Type` header along with `Accept` header too

Comment: I'm able to do `httpPost.setEntity((HttpEntity) mainMap);` should it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GSON library and  define a class with every field on it like below

```
Class Car { String name; String color;}
```

and pass data to it post this class.
or you can follow this link

[HTTP POST using JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java)