# How to send param to post http request?

Tags: javascript, java, http, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I have a javaScript code where i am sending http post with some parameters. Post parameter is a json that looks like this: 
`{"tokenRequest":{"authSpecification":{"authToken":"T7SUNv0j2eRTeu04tVbcSa0LHN1YnNjcmliZXItMTk2LDEsRk9YVEVMLDE5NiwxMT"},"contentSpecification":{"contentId":"abc"}}}`

In JavaScript, I simply open request, set headers and send parameters. Post request looks like:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
request.send(tokenRequestJSON); //tokenRequestJSON is the json parameter mentioned above
```

Now I need to make same call in Java (due to some internal POC requirement). For that I did following:

```
AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
Map<String,String> httpHeaders = new HashMap<>();
httpHeaders.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
for (Map.Entry header : httpHeaders.entrySet()) {
                asyncHttpClient.addHeader((String)header.getKey(), (String)header.getValue());
            }
RequestParams postData1 = new RequestParams();
String tokenRequest1 = "{\"tokenRequest\":{\"authSpecification\":{\"authToken\":\"T7SUNv0j2eRTeu04tVbcSa0LHN1YnNjcmliZXItMTk2LDEsRk9YVEVMLDE5NiwxMT\"},\"contentSpecification\":{\"contentId\":\"abc\"}}}";
postData1.put("arg0", tokenRequest1);
asyncHttpClient.post(url, postData1, new ResponseHandler());
```

But it is giving me error. `{"errorResponse": {"status": "ERROR", "errorCode": "MDRM-0002", "errorMessage": "Json body not properly formed (No JSON object could be decoded)"}}`

I am new to Java, I may be missing some basic stuff. Do you know, why request from java is failing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) ?

```
RequestParams postData1 = new RequestParams();
postData1.put("arg0", tokenRequest1) // this is not a json object, not the body of the request.
```

Request param is param on the url, for example, "date" is a request param:
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/user/1234/invoices?date=12-05-2013

Comment: Yes I am using AyncHttpClient. Then how should I send parameters to http post in Java?

Comment: Here, there is many example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181534/http-post-using-json-in-java

Comment: Thanks man. You are right, I was passing JSON in RequestParams which was wrong. Now I am using StringEntity for JSON and it worked.