# Sending and Receivng SMS with Java COMM API

Tags: java, java-communication-api

I stumbled upon [this](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=22) guide on how to use it, but being the beginner that I am, it confused me on how to use it until I saw the answer in [this](http://qa.java-samples.com/questions/805/how-to-send-sms) guide.

However, I noticed that one of the five files is already named SMSClient and the step two in the second guide duplicates that file so I skipped it and headed for step three which was confusing since I got an error in this line:

`SMSClient smsc = SMSClient(0);`

I placed all the five java files plus the SendSMS.java file in the (default package) package of the src package, however Eclipse could not seem to find the SMSClient.java file.

Sorry if this is a very basic question, I've yet to have any lessons with Java at all and I'm feeling my way through these. Any help will be very much appreciated, may it be clarifications regarding the codes above or a better alternative to sending/receiving text messages. Thank you.

Comment: show stack-trace from your error, and maye some more code.

Comment: The code are the exact same code in the links above.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16083393/597657

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use one of these alternative because they are supported and used by many developers:

A better alternative for SMS Send/Receive is **Logica Open SMPP** from [HERE](http://opensmpp.logica.com/CommonPart/Introduction/Introduction.htm).. It's an open source API based on **JAVA** providing you with all you need in SMS technology. The website also has an **SMC Simulator** for testing which is very helpful..

Another alternative is **Kannel: Open Source WAP and SMS Gateway** from [Here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://www.kannel.org/&ei=27Z2UcqbIpSp7Abeg4DABw&usg=AFQjCNE68vF4y1_4VGZd9jlseb6vPVGUXg&bvm=bv.45512109,d.ZGU) it's an open source API based on Linux which you can easily configure and you can use web services to send and receive SMS or SQLBox to send and receive through **DB Transactions**.. I personally use **Kannel**

Check the Documentation of Kannel from [Here](http://www.kannel.org/doc.shtml)

Comment: Does Kannel work on the Mac OSX? It seems like the developers favor the use of Linux.

Comment: Currently it's not working on Mac but there are some tries from some developers to compile Kannel for Mac... You would better use Logica Open SMPP http://opensmpp.logica.com/CommonPart/Introduction/Introduction.htm while it's written in Java which you can run anywhere