# Sending SMS via Java web applications

Tags: java, web, sms

Have you seen how some companies send SMS in order to send access code etc? I am also in need of something like that. I have Java web application developed using JSP and Servlet. Through this application, I need to send SMS messages to some selected people.

I am open for free or paid APIs. But that API should support web based apps and should have the capability to send messages to Sri Lanka.

I went through lot of stuff like SMS Lib etc, but they are not built for web applications.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570410/how-to-send-sms-in-java there are a few options

Comment: You should use twilio service.It provide api as well as code too. It has sms and call functionality.

Comment: @Darshan: Checked. Unfortunately, it costs 4 times more than what SL local SMS could cost.

Answer (score 0):

You should see [Simplewire Java SMS Software Development Kit](http://www.tucows.com/preview/221572)

[Sending and receiving SMS From Java using the Ozeki Java SMS SDK](http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=584)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [OpenMarket Sms API](https://www.openmarket.com/customer-center/documentation/SMSHTTP_APIGuide/index.htm). Its good and quite economical also.