# Receiving and Sending SMS from j2ee web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, sms

My requirement is "My web-application will accept sms from users. According to the content of SMS and number from which SMS has been sent, the application will perform specific action."

Can you please guide me in this?

EDIT :
    Please suggest me some good SMS gateway or some good library to implement this. When I researched, I found so many SMS gateways available on internet, but most of them were serving US/UK. My project is India-specific.

Note : I am still researching for the best possible solution and have not started coding and seeking your advice for the same. Hence, I can not produce any code here.

Regards,
Saurabh

Comment: looks like someone has given you a problem definition from a book.

Comment: ohh...have I written it so well? your comment is encouraging me to write a book. Jokes apart! but this is what I want to implement. I browsed through the internet, holding Google's hand and found some SMS gateways, but could not find India-specific SMS gateway which will help me in achieving above thing. My googling skills might not be that good probably.

Comment: Certainly. Retrieve SMS from the users via your web app, and based on the content of the SMS and which phone it was sent from, make your app do different things. Helpful? If you want help, ask specific questions. If you want someone to write your code, visit a more appropriate site like [RentaCoder](http://www.rentacoder.com). If you want to show what you've tried so far and explain what part isn't working as you'd expect or where you're having trouble, someone here will probably be glad to help, but you have to show you're at least putting some effort into solving it yourself.

Comment: Possible solved here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545441/how-can-i-send-an-sms-from-java

Comment: @Ken - +1 for your advice. Thanks for that. I don't really want anybody to code my application. I am just asking the best possible SMS gateway / library to implement gateway to solve this problem. Seeking or advice from someone who has already done such sort of thing. I have edited my question. Please see if it sounds good now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you will have to use a web service that provides you with the functionality of receiving SMS. Your computer cannot send or receive SMS through the air without a device connected to it or a service that provides it.

This might help https://www.twilio.com.