# how do I know if SMS has reached at destination in Twilio

Tags: java, sms, twilio, sms-gateway

i am developing a web app and in that I am sending SMS using twilio gateway.I need to show on my page the status of SMS.If SMS is sent then it will show delivered else it will show pending. So please tell me how do i know whether the message has been delivered or not.

Following is the sample code

```
public class Example {

  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "AC5b8866a232v3b63bfgh0f9a872b2dfddd";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "7a0068ca7d07036cbbddeba03370aujdhnm";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    params.put("To", "+number");
    params.put("From", "+number");
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
    SmsFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getSmsFactory();
    Sms message = messageFactory.create(params);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

First of all please note that the [SmsMessages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms) resource has been deprecated and you should now be using the new [Messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) endpoint.  You can check out the [Sending SMS Messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/sms/sending-via-rest) quickstart for updated Java code that shows how to use the new resource with the Java helper library.

Second, in order to receive notifications as a Messages status changes you should include the [StatusCallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-optional) parameter when you send the Message.  Including this parameter tells Twilio to make a request to the parameters URL when the message status changes.

Also note since its not clear from your post title, the "sent" status simple means that Twilio successfully sent the message to the carrier.  It does not necessarily mean that the carrier was able to deliver the message to the intended recipient.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am using message.getStatus() and it shows me queued.But Nishants answer tells that getstatus will show sent,sending,queued

Comment: Thank for the answer,I am confused with this line **First of all please note that the SmsMessages resource has been deprecated and you should now be using the new Messages endpoint**. Please tell me that code in the question is deprecated or not.Is this the right way of using.

Comment: The code in your post will still work, but has been deprecated.  Check out the link to the quickstart I included in my answer for the correct Java code to use.  Calling getStatus simply returns whatever the value of the Status parameter that Twilio sent in its response to your request to the REST API.  Twilio has no way of updating this response once its sent to you, so the value of getStatus will always be the same.  If you want to be notified as the messags status changes over time you need to use the StatusCallback as I suggested.  Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for replying,+1 for your help.Well If i am calling message.getStatus() then it prints queued,how ever if i call client.getAccount().getSms(message.getSid()).getStatus() it prints sent.Please tell me how can i get sending status

Comment: i am totally confused.Tell me can i use this https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/sms/sending-via-rest. iF tes then why you provided this https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message

Comment: So in your code your using: SmsFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getSmsFactory();   But if you look at the code in the sample, you will see its using MessageFactory messageFactory = account.getMessageFactory();    See how the class name has changed?

Comment: Thanks devin for all your help.Well one last query do twilio has the facility to send SMS later.All the SMS are sent immediaitely,suppose I want to send a sms now but I want it to be delivred after 5 days,is it possible usig twilio API

Comment: We do not currently offer any kind of message scheduling capability.  You would need to create your own service to do this.

Comment: How long does it take for a message to turn to  "sent" from "queued"? 1 min? 30 mins? 1 hour? An sms I'm trying to send has been queued for 10 mins already. Is it normal? It's in the production.

Answer (score 1):

[`Message.getStatus()`](http://twilio.github.io/twilio-java/com/twilio/sdk/resource/instance/Message.html#getStatus%28%29) is what you need. I think the response is one of `queued`, `sending`, `sent`, or `failed`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,it only shows me queued but how to know other 2 responses(sending,sent).If i give wrong mobile number then it throws exception

Comment: any solutions you have?